# Spread Emberjs templates in different folders

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

Is there an addons for Emberjs which spreads templates in different folders?

I would like e.g. to have:

```
templates/components/modals/my-modal.hbs
templates/components/modals/my-modal2.hbs
templates/components/widgets/my-widget.hbs
templates/components/widgets/my-widget2.hbs
...
```

Comment: We're all waiting for [module unification](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6332).

Comment: In the mean time you can still get the structure that you want but the `app/components` folder will have to match.

Comment: Thanks lux, this seems to be a long way to go ;)